# Make First Letter of an Array Uppercase in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I'm trying to retrieve strings from my database using Laravel Eloquent queries. However, the data I get is in full caps. I want only the first letter to be in uppercase. Can anybody help me out?

```php
$main = DB::table('master_accountsmain')->get()
```

I'm passing the main to my views using...

```
return view('home', 'main' => $main);
```

I have tried using `ucfirst($main),` but it does not work. The data remains in uppercase.

Comment: `$main` is array not a string which will convert into lower case

Comment: Yes I am having an issue with converting the array to have first letter with uppercase @AyazShah

Comment: What is the content of `$main`?

Comment: ucfirst(strtolower($main[0]->property)) ? Main is an array of objects because you're using ->get(); if you were fetching just one with ->first() it would return an eloquent object.

Comment: the $main looks like this $main = [ 'JOHN', 'DOE', 'GUIDE' ] @Jerodev

Comment: What version of Laravel are you on? This query should return a Collection.

Comment: Thank you very much @luminoslty. It worked like a charm!! You could put your answer in the other part so I could give it a tick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ucfirst(strtolower($main[0]->property))` is what you want to do.

`$main` is an array of objects because you're using `->get();`

If you were fetching just one with `->first();` it would return an eloquent object and you would simply call `ucfirst(strtolower($main->property))`

If you have more than one result you could simply loop over or use fancy array functions builtin to php.

If it is an eloquent collection they have built in methods such as `->each()` that allow you to map an array.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change it in lower case first with `strtolower()` then your `ucfirst` will work fine. Try it as below in order to make it works.

```
ucfirst(strtolower($main));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't `ucfirst($array)`.
You need to get the element of `$array`.
Like

```
$fname = ucfirst(strtolower($array->fname));
```